# Query job doesn't work from external table (linked google drive file) doesn't work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm learning python with bigquery by doing small project and I have no idea why my query doesn't work in python while working properly in bigquery web gui. If I'm running any other queries from standard dataset tables it works. I've added google drive scoopes to default credentials because I had auth error before. Just external table from google drive is not working and I'm getting error

> google.cloud.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.

My standard google function:

```
def query_shakespeare(query):

    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    query_job = client.run_async_query(job_name, query)

    query_job.begin()
    query_job.result()

    destination_table = query_job.destination
    destination_table.reload()
    for row in destination_table.fetch_data():
        print(row)
```

And my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [gdocs_names.name_0001]
```

Running it by web -> compose query last 3s and works.
It works also using command line:

```
bg query "SELECT * FROM [gdocs_names.name_0001]"
```

Comment: I wonder how you specify in your script that the source for the query is a google drive doc?

Comment: @WillianFuks 
I didn't. I just created a permanent external table from Google Sheets (first tab only) so with that I can then run a query against the table as if it were a native BigQuery table.
Command line bq query works
Web gui works
Python script doesn't

Comment: Funny thing, I created a federated table in the webUI and when trying to query it in CLI I just get the message `Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.`. When testing in google shell, then I got the same error than you did. How did you manage to query it using the CLI? Supposedly you have to add GDrive scopes in the OAuth but neither `--enable-gdrive-access` nor `--enable_gdrive=True` worked.

Comment: @WillianFuks
Web gui is asking you to access google drive
If we talk about console I had to run 

gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,... (and some standard api like mailinfo + cloud)

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time on that, there is a flag --enable_gdrive that you need to set to true like this:

```
bg query --enable_gdrive=true "SELECT * FROM [gdocs_names.name_0001]"
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access`